# Using a shadow from Photoshop in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I'm designing a Billboard in Illustrator. The design on the billboard shows two layers - dropping a thin line of shadow. I've read somewhere, that the shadow looks better if you make it in Photoshop and then put it in Illustrator instead of just making it in Illustrator. But I'm designing a billboard in ratio 1:10 and I'm not sure if the shadow, made in Photoshop, will look good when it's "stretched". Is in this case best, if I make the shadow in Illustrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating in Illustrator, there's no need to implement embedded or linked raster files for a shadow. Use Illustrator.

While Photoshop offers a bit more flexibility in terms of noise and dithering than Illustrator will -- it is highly unlikely, at billboard size, those variances would be of any visual merit.

Comment: Thank you! One extra question if I may... I also have a photo on the billboard - It's blurred, used just for a background, so the billboard doesn't look so plain. It's 300 dpi, cause it's made in 1:10 ratio. But the image size is 2000 x 1324 px. Is that appropriate fot a billboard 300 x 400 cm?

Comment: @Evelynn20  2000 pixels in 400 cm  means 2 mm pixel size. That grid is surely visible when the watcher is at 1 m distance. But he probably is further. Make on the screen a photo in so high zoom that the pixels are 2 millimeters. Then walk further to see how far away that image should be watched without seeing the pixels. Also consult your printer what is their pixel size in that large prints.